# How do I count the number of cells in a column against criteria in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I need help creating a formula to count number of unique delivery stops each day.  The table below is similar to my actual data.

| Name | Address | Sun | Mon | Tues | Wed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 1 Main St | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| George | 3 Main St | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Tom | 4 Main St | 4 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Harry | 1 Main St | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Randy | 1 Main St | 0 | 0 | 4 | 2 |
| Homer | 5 Main St | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Bill | 10 Main St | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Jim | 1 Main St | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Joe | 2 Main St | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

For instance, "1 Main St" is marked 4 times on the chart, but on Sunday there were 2 deliveries but only 1 actual stop at that location.

How would I go about calculating that based with a formula?  I originally tried a ```=SUMPRODUCT```` but it wasn't calculating correctly, it would count each delivery stop, I'm not sure how to make it not count 0's and to combine multiple deliveries to the same address as a single delivery.

My last formula was "`=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF($D$6:$D$96,$D$6:$D$96)=1)*$J$8:$J$98)`

Where Column D is the addresses and J starts the delivery counts on Sunday.

Thanks

*EDIT*
Sorry, I wasn't clear with my question: I need a way to count the number of stops made per day (so if an address has multiple deliveries to different people, it's just counted as a single stop and 0's are skipped).  Using Excel 2013

Comment: I see two different names having a delivery on `1 Main St` with a value > 0 on `Sun`. Why would this count as one stop? Also how would you want your result data to look like?

Comment: I think the answer to you question resides in the "Array Formulas" environment. I'm expecting that somebody could formulate this problem.

Comment: Sorry, P.b,  I edited my question to add clarity.   It would count as 1 stop because there are multiple people getting a delivery at that address, but it's only 1 stop (think an apartment building, lots of people but only 1 street/building address).

Answer (score 0):

After many, many attempts, here it is...

## Answer:

```
=SUM(IF(LEN(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B10;C2:C10>0;0);FALSE;FALSE))>1;1;0))
```

*Where B2 is the first address, C2 is the first row under sunday.*

This will give you unique delivery locations. So, if you visit the same place multiple times in one day, it is still counted as 1. If 0, it is counted as 0.

Your question was VERY unclear. Next time around, please tell us what you want the result to be.

This answer will give 6 for Sunday. If there are no deliveries, it will be zero. This last point took me hours to solve. COUNTIF won't work on single cells, only arrays. COUNT only works on numbers, COUNTA... Well, apparently COUNTA counts empty arrays (like if FILTER returns nothing). So I had to get the length (>1 for some reason). If it was greater than 1 in length, add 1, otherwise 0. And finally SUM it all.

Like I said, this is to calculate deliveries on Sunday, so this formula will be repeated for the other days.

*Hope you like it!* ^_^

Comment: Thanks, I think this is close, but I can't use the `UNIQUE` function in Excel 2013.  I'm going to try and work with the formula you came up with and modify it, if I can I'll update with it and mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Oh no! Okay, I wasn't aware. Maybe [this](https://www.listendata.com/2013/05/excel-3-ways-to-extract-unique-values.html) or [this](https://www.get-digital-help.com/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/) could help?